# WhatsApp Live Database on Rooted Device

Tags: android, root, whatsapp

I rooted my device and pull out the WhatsApp key in data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key and the database in data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db and sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/msgstore.db.crypt12.

I managed to read the SQLite database of WhatsApp messages all right, but these're not live!  I need to go to WhatsApp to do a backup to get live database.  Is these any way for me to do that perhaps with an ADB command or is there some other ways to do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

First install [ADB Insecure](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.adbd&hl=es) in the terminal.

Then use:

adb pull data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db

That will copy the msgstoredb database in the ADB directory. Here you could open it with an SQLite viewer.